# Why we don't get a Deadlock here?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, deadlock

While code reviewing myself work, I spotted a very interesting piece of code where I can swear it would cause a deadlock, but I've tested it many times, with multiple threads, and could not get any.

it's puzzling me so hard that I decided to ask it here.
So the assumption is that the LOCK doesn't lock for the same thread, but I would  like to confirm it.
Following the piece of code

```
public class SplitService : ISplitService
{
    private IRecordService recordService;

    public SplitService(IRecordService recordService)
    {
        this.recordService = recordService;
    }

    private ConcurrentQueue<Batch> _batches = new ConcurrentQueue<Batch>();

    public void Feed(Something r)
    {
        lock (this.recordService)
        {
            if (!this.recordService.CanAppend(r))
            {
                Flush();
            }
            this.recordService.Append(r);
        }           
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        lock (this.recordService)
        {
            if (!this.recordService.Any()) return;

            var record = this.recordService.GetBatch();
            _batches.Enqueue(record);

            this.recordService.Clean();
        }           
    }

    public IEnumerable<Batch> Get()
    {
        while (_batches.Any())
        {
            if (_batches.TryDequeue(out Batch batch))
            {
                yield return batch;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can notice, the method `Feed` locks into a **object**, and if the same returns false for CanAppend it call the `Flush` method that also **try to lock the same object**.
So I would expect a deadlock there

---

Extrapolating a bit after understanding it, as Lock is recursive, we can assume that this will also work:

```
lock(locker){           
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
   await new Task(() => {
        lock(locker){                   
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World from locker");
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix `lock` with the async/await programming model. Instead use a SemaphoreSlim which has a `WaitAsync` method that plays nice with async/await.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Monitor` objects is C# are recursive, so you just have to remember to unlock them as many times as you lock them. For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
lock(someObject)
{
  lock(someObject)
  {
    lock(someObject)
    {
       Consolw.WriteLine("hello world")
    }
  }
}
```

It's important to realize that lock is only recursive once you've acquired the lock. If thread A has acquired the lock and then thread B tries to acquire the lock then B will block until thread A releases the lock.

Comment: so I can even be in a different context when lock a object?
Let's say
Lock_objectA => await new_Thread_that_Lock_objectA, this will also be ok?

Comment: @NicollasBraga - Locking on a different thread many lead to deadlock if you're not careful. When a lock is taken it is bound to a thread. The thread it is bound to can repeatedly  lock it. However, other threads will block until the lock has been fully released.

Comment: @NicollasBraga - Don't edit the answer. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @Sean, It doesn't matter how many threads call in to the OP's example because any given call only locks one lock. In order to achieve a classic deadlock, the code has to try to acquire two different locks at the same time, and code running in two or more threads has to acquire the same two locks, but in the opposite order.

Answer (score 3):

For a deadlock, you need 2 accessors and 2 resources. In this case there's only one resource, so everyone will wait patiently for it.